# Removing high outliers from a list using column of cells. Array? Linked List? VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a distribution of numbers on the order of 600k values that will look like this:

1, 500, 94, 65, 37, 1000, 1505 and so on.

Numbers can be repeated.  I want to remove the outliers from the top because the concentration of numbers will be near 10 and the outliers are skewing my data (ie the distribution of the numbers I’m concerned with starts with 1 and can range to near 25).

First, I take this list, and sort it in ascending order:

1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 up to maybe 1500, 1505, 1600, 1666, etc.

Then I go to the highest value in the list, start removing points and calculating an average and standard deviation at each removal. I stop when the distribution below this point becomes as normal as possible.  At the moment I am using a stopping point of stdev/average = 0.4.  I could use other parameters (median, mode, mean) but at this point it's ancillary to the discussion I would like to have.

To do this, I first tried removing the points 1 at a time and recalculated the average and stdev, stopping when my set parameter was met.  This takes way too long.  So I decided to reduce the number of calculations being done.  I did this by only calculating the average and stdev at halfway points up or down the list and moved up or down depending on the value of my parameter (ie stdev/ave < 0.4 move halfway up from this point, stdev/ave > 0.4 move halfway down from this point).  I then delete everything from the list with a higher measurement once the critical point in my parameter was met (ie the point in the list where stdev/ave dropped below 0.4).

My question is, does anyone have any suggestions on how I might get this thing to run faster?  Maybe store the list as an array?  Or just keeping working with the list?  Is there another object I can work with in vba like a linked list maybe that might run quicker?  Here’s my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveHighOutliers()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Double      'iterator for list position
Dim j As Double      '0.5 multiplier
Dim cv As Double     'critical value
Dim std As Double    'critical value 2
Dim numRows As Double

numRows = CountRows    'separate module to count the number of rows containing data
i = numRows - 1        'my first set point is the second to last and last values in the list
j = Round(i* 0.5, 0)   'used to move 1/2 way up or down the remainder of the list
cv = WorksheetFunction.stdev(Range("F1:F" & i)) / WorksheetFunction.average(Range("F1:F" & i)) ‘critcal value
If cv < 0.4 Then
GoTo jump1             'if list is already at a point at or below normal distribution don't enter loop
Else
Do
    If j < 1 Then      'if j less than 1 causes an infinite loop, at this point, one point down will be critical value to exit loop
    i = i - 1
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.stdev(Range("F1:F" & i)) / WorksheetFunction.average(Range("F1:F" & i)) > 0.4 And WorksheetFunction.stdev(Range("F1:F" & i + 1)) / WorksheetFunction.average(Range("F1:F" & i + 1)) > 0.4 Then
        i = Round(i - (i * (j / i)), 0)   'if too high in the list move down 1/2 way
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.stdev(Range("F1:F" & i)) / WorksheetFunction.average(Range("F1:F" & i)) < 0.4 And WorksheetFunction.stdev(Range("F1:F" & i + 1)) / WorksheetFunction.average(Range("F1:F" & i + 1)) < 0.4 Then
        i = Round((i + (i * (j / i))), 0) 'if too low in the list move up 1/2 way
    End If
j = Round(j * 0.5, 0)   'reduce the 1/2 way iterator
cv = WorksheetFunction.stdev(Range("F1:F" & i)) / WorksheetFunction.average(Range("F1:F" & i))      'recalculate cv
cv2 = WorksheetFunction.stdev(Range("F1:F" & i + 1)) / WorksheetFunction.average(Range("F1:F" & i + 1))  'recalculate cv2
Loop Until cv <= 0.4 And cv2 > 0.4            'exit loop when critial value reached
Range("A" & i + 1 & ":H" & numRows).Select
Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp                  'delete the outliers
jump1:
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image: distribution of noise]

Comment: Your algorithm is the cause of your performance problem, not the data structures or how you access them. If you calculate the mean you can score each data point based on its impact to the overall standard deviation and then calculate which range of data points meets your criteria. Your present solution is basically just trial and error - sort out the math *first*, and *then* concentrate on the implementation.

Comment: Forgive my naïveté but I’m not understanding (I’m not a statistician). I’d love to be able to do this an easier better way! This is a mash of noise and signal data. I need to remove the signal without having to open a visual representation, interpret the data. If I were to plot this distribution before removing the signal, it would appear as a normal distribution with a long low tail to the right, a large majority of which isn’t nor should be a part of the distribution of noise.